# Updating an app to Angular 8 from Angular 5, causes styling issues

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, single-page-application, angular8

I have an project which uses Angular 5.2. Recently we updated the project to Angular 8 and updated the Angular CLI in the process too. 
After doing the code refactoring which is required by Angular 8, the app builds without any issue. However the styling seems to be off. Nav bar is not displayed as it should, and some of the styling of buttons are not rendered properly. Bootstrap elements are used and some of them;we override with our sass styling.

Previosuly to fix an error during the build, I had to install tether separately(manually) which was a dependency for bootstrap.

**Before Update - Angular 5.2:** 
[image: Angular 5.2 - Before Update]

**After Update - Angular 8:**
[image: Angular 8 - After Update]

I also get an error when try to navigate to some routes within the app as well
[image: Error on navigate]

I have tried a lot of different stuff like reinstalling the dependencies and redoing the instructions on Angular update guide and still there's no progress. Anyone has an idea why this is happening?

Comment: You have to take in a consideration that probably some of the dependencies you are using are not compatible with Angular 8.

Comment: Do you have node types in your tsconfig?

Comment: @dino yes, I think it might be a case as well, but currently nothing is giving me an error, therefore I'm not able to determine what exactly causes this issue. I have tries removing some dependencies which i thought might be causing the problem, but still the styling issue wasn't solved.

Comment: @Robertgarcia I'm not clear about what you asked? Are you asking about typeRoots?

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your polyfill

```
(window as any).global = window;
```

The [ng2-dragula](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula) you are using, mentions this problem in their setup guide.

> This is a temporary workaround for [#849](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula/issues/849), while upstream dragula still
>   relies on global.

Comment: Thanks a lot!, This fixed the issue related to the dragula. Using the workaround till i try to get the styling issue fixed as well. I thought both the cases were related so i didn't search specifically about the dragula issue and missed it.